# Single dash for argparse long options

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

Is it possible to make it so that `--longoption` is represented as `-longoption` using argparse?

[`argparse.prefix_chars`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) doesn't work, as it is assumed that the prefix char would be repeated for a long option.

I'm thinking perhaps there is a way to turn off short options and allow long options to use a single dash instead of a double dash. Something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.turn_off_short_opts()
```

Can this be done? If not, what can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: `-longoption` means a completely different thing: It means `-l` `-o` `-n` `-g` `-p` `-t` `-i` -- which is to say, it sets a flag per letter. Making this usage mean anything else would be very confusing for users.

Comment: Why do you want single dash long options?

Comment: @Falmarri Because I am required to do so to fit the conventions of my workplace

Comment: You can, of course, munge the list before passing it to argparse -- doubling any single dash prefixes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh my goodness. Thank you so much; don't know why that never occurred to me. But then how do I get the help to show properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Single dash long arguments aren't a problem:

```
In [250]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [251]: p.add_argument('-longargument')
Out[251]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-longargument'], dest='longargument', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [252]: p.parse_args(['-long','test'])
Out[252]: Namespace(longargument='test')

In [253]: p.parse_args(['-l','test'])
Out[253]: Namespace(longargument='test')
```

I'd have to double check the code, but I don't think the distinction between long and short options is that significant.  When creating the action, all are added to the `option_strings` attribute.  The long (multicharacter) string is used to set the 'dest', but you can also set that yourself.

The behavior that `Duffy` cites: `longoption means a completely different thing: It means -l -o -n -g -p -t -i` is more nuanced.  If `-l`,`-o`, etc are all defined and don't require arguments it will use interpretation.  But it doesn't interfer with regular interpretation of `-longoption`.  But you should be aware of such interpretations, and test things during development.

---

Here's the code used to set the `dest` for optionals:

```
    if dest is None:
        if long_option_strings:
            dest_option_string = long_option_strings[0]
        else:
            dest_option_string = option_strings[0]
```

just before this it collected the strings with `--` into the long_option_string` list.  But if there isn't such a string, it uses the first string.

```
In [270]: p.add_argument('-longargument','-l','--longish')
Out[270]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-longargument', '-l', '--longish'], dest='longish', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

Here `--longish` was used instead of `-longargument`.

The only other place that looks at option string length is the special handling of the `-xyz`, which focuses on the single character strings ('-x', '-y', '-z').

Comment: I just tried that, but it still doesn't recognize `-help`, though it does recognize `-h` and `--help`. (Background: What I'd like is something similar to the behavior of Perl's `Getopt::Long`, which allows either `-option` or `--option`. I'm not interested in supporting single-character options. I'm sure I could work around the `-help` glitch, but it's probably not worth the effort, so I guess I'll just go with the double hyphen.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, you'd have create the parser with `add_help=False`, and add your own `add_argument('-h', '-help', '--help', '--ayudame', action='help')`; in other words explicitly define '-help' as a valid flag string.  The default help does not do that.  When I wrote that '-longargument' is valid, I did not mean that it will work if you just define '--longargument'.  You have to list all flag strings you want to allow (though unambiguous abbreviations also work).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127366/single-dash-for-argparse-long-options#comment50267126_31127366) for the idea.

Just go through `sys.argv` beforehand and replace each `-long-option` with `--long-option`, but remember to intercept the parser's help message too. Something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument(('-h', '--help'), help='Show this message and quit', action='count')
# add other args

new_argv = []
for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg.startswith('-') and len(arg) > 2:
        arg = '-' + arg
    new_argv.append(arg)
sys.argv = new_argv

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.help:
    help_string = parser.format_help()
    print(help_string.replace('--', '-'))
    parser.exit(0)
```

Comment: To make it more compact as a one-liner:

sys.argv = [re.sub(r'^-([^-]+)', '--\g<1>', x) for x in sys.argv]